# Laravel 4.1 routing issues ErrorException route not defined

Tags: laravel, routes

I am testing button

```
Button onclick="window.location ='{{ route('books.index') }}'
```

Which returns index page but testing another button

`onclick="window.location ='{{ route('books.index2') }}'`

returns error message (**`ErrorException Route [books.index2] not defined`**)

functions in ***Bookcontroller.php*** are

```
public function index() {
    return View::make('books/bookindex');
}


public function index2() {
    return View::make('books/bookindex');
}
```

Function in ***routes.php***

```
Route::resource('books', 'BookController');
```

Why some functions are working but ohers not? Can some help.Thank you.

Comment: 4.1 ? really i think either 5.1 or 4.2 .

Comment: Version 4.1.21 I have to work with this version.

Comment: there is other way's of doing this

Comment: tell me more about it

Comment: try using this Route::get('/index',['as' => 'book.index', 'uses' => 'BookController@index']);                                               
Route::get('/index2',['as' => 'book.index2', 'uses' => 'BookController@index2']);

Comment: HI . I tried     :Route::get('/index2',['as' => 'book.index2', 'uses' => 'BookController@index2'])                                                                                                        and got and error ;                                                                                                                                            ErrorException 

Route [books.index2] not defined.

Comment: did you get this error for both routes ?